# exception 'Viewflex\Forex\ForexException' with message 'Error retrieving exchange rate

Tags: php, laravel, forex

am using version of this package "viewflex/forex": "^0.1.1"
But while updating the currency rate for -

```
$usdRate = $server->getRate('USD', 'INR');
```

Getting error as below
exception 'Viewflex\Forex\ForexException' with message 'Error retrieving exchange rate.

Any Help!!!
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into their souce code, I see this:

https://github.com/viewflex/forex/blob/master/src/Forex.php#L57-L68

```
        if (
            array_key_exists('rates', $content)
            && array_key_exists($target, $content['rates'])
            && $content['rates'][$target]
        ) {
            $rate = floatval($content['rates'][$target]);
        } else {
            throw new ForexException('Error retrieving exchange rate.');
        }
        if($rate <= 0)
            throw new ForexException('Error retrieving exchange rate.');
```

So it appears that if the response doesn't contain the required info it will throw the exception. Also, if it passes the first check but the rate is < 0, it also throws an exception. So it doesn't actually look like you've done anything wrong.

Looking further, I see it makes this call:

```
$response = $this->request('https://api.fixer.io/latest?base='.$source.'&symbols='.$target);
```

I translated this based on your code to:

https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD&symbols=INR

Which if you click that link, will give you the answer:

```
0   "#################################################################################################################################"
1   "#                                                                                                                               #"
2   "# IMPORTANT - PLEASE UPDATE YOUR API ENDPOINT                                                                                   #"
3   "#                                                                                                                               #"
4   "# This API endpoint is deprecated and has now been shut down. To keep using the Fixer API, please update your integration       #"
5   "# to use the new Fixer API endpoint, designed as a simple drop-in replacement.                                                  #"
6   "# You will be required to create an account at https://fixer.io and obtain an API access key.                                   #"
7   "#                                                                                                                               #"
8   "# For more information on how to upgrade please visit our Github Tutorial at: https://github.com/fixerAPI/fixer#readme          #"
9   "#                                                                                                                               #"
a   "#################################################################################################################################"
```

It looks like the library is out of date.

Either use a different lib, or get it working again.

To get around this, you can firstly create an account with the new api, sign up for github if you arent already, fork the repository, change this line https://github.com/viewflex/forex/blob/master/src/Forex.php#L53, and either send a pull request, or change the composer package name https://github.com/viewflex/forex/blob/master/composer.json#L2 and register your own new package with https://packagist.org/ (change all the file namespaces too if you do that.)

If you sign up for the new API and send the new endpoint, I can send the guy a pull request with the fix.

Comment: Yes, this would work, but i wouldn't recommend doing that because every time i run composer update i should go and re enter my new api key which is not very practical.

Comment: Please tell me you are NOT editing vendor files? Updating the code to the latest version should not affect any of your code! (unless you upgrade to a major version, in which case you need to check the changelog and make whatever tweaks it says you need to make)

Comment: now i see that in your answer you are meant to make my own package just like viewflex/forex and change the api_key? is this true?

Comment: Your API key is NOT in their package, why would it be? They just need to change the API URL they are calling. I am concerned that you think your API key has to be in their code, so I'll ask again. Have you been altering files in the vendor folder?

Comment: Look, I'll tell you what. Sign up to https://fixer.io and get a new API key. I'll update the guys package and send him a pull request once you send me the real URL it should be calling (check API docs on their site). Then you just need to update the package once he's merged the change in, and all will start working again.

Comment: No i didn't alter files in vendor and no one should i know that, Thank you but i already alter my code to use a different package "laravel-swap", but if you want to here is the url to call "http://data.fixer.io/api/convert? access_key=API_KEY&from=GBP&to=JPY&amount=25", it may help someone that wanna stick to "viewflex/forex".
Thank you anyway :)

Comment: Just had a look at that package. I don't like it. Statics etc (shudders). Why tightly couple an API library with Laravel? I'd prefer using his ACTUAL library here https://github.com/florianv/swap rather than some facade bundle thing

Comment: anyway, glad you got sorted